# Dynamic Forms Won't Correctly Insert Into MySQL Database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

```
<body>
     <?php
        $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','cash');
        $query = "SELECT DISTINCT category FROM cash";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        $dropDownList = '<select name="names[]"><option value = "">---Select---</option>';
        while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $dropDownList .= "<option value='" . $d['category'] . "'>" . $d['category'] . "</option>";
        }
        $dropDownList .= '</select>';

    ?>     


    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var InputsWrapper = $("#InputsWrapper");
        var AddButton = $("#AddMoreFileBox");
        var dropOption = <?php echo json_encode($dropDownList) ?>;
        var x = InputsWrapper.length;
        var FieldCount = 1;
        $(AddButton).click(function(e)//on add input button click
        {

            FieldCount++;
            $(InputsWrapper).append('<tr><td>'+dropOption+'<td><input type="text" name="cate[]" id="categ"/></td><td><input type="number" name="money[]" id="amount"/></td></tr>'); 
            x++;
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
     <form action="selectxpprocess.php" method="post">

     <table id="InputsWrapper" >
            <tr>
                <span class="small"><a href="#" id="AddMoreFileBox" class="btn btn-info">Add More Field</a></span>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for='names[]'>Category:</label></td>
                <td><label for='cate[]'>New Category:</label></td>
                <td><label for='money[]'>Amount:</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $dropDownList?></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="cate[]" id="categ"/></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="money[]" id="amount"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" />
           </form>

</body>
```

Here's my first page. I have a button that when you click it another Dropdown, text box, and number input will pop up. The condition I want is if nothing is selected in the dropdown then get data from the textbox. After that pass the corresponding amount value to the database.

```
<?php

 $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','cash');


if($_POST['names'] != '' && $_POST['cate'] == '') {
    foreach($_POST['names'] as $catego) {
        foreach($_POST['money'] as $amo){
            mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO cash (category, amount) VALUES ('".$catego."','".$amo."')");
        }
    } 
}else {
    foreach($_POST['cate'] as $categ) {
        foreach($_POST['money'] as $amo){
            mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO cash (category, amount) VALUES ('".$categ."','".$amo."')");
        }
    }
}

$_POST=array();
mysqli_close($con);
header("Location: selectxp.php");
exit;

?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `$_POST['names']` & `$_POST['cate']` are arrays you can't check them as a string, ie. `if($_POST['names'] != '' && $_POST['cate'] == '')`. Also, you are nesting your loops, where instead you need to link them by the array keys. Something like -

```
foreach($_POST['names'] as $key => $val){
    if($_POST['names'][$key] != '' && $_POST['cate'][$key] == '') {
        $catego = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['names'][$key]);
        $amo = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['money'][$key]); 
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO cash (category, amount) VALUES ('".$catego."','".$amo."')");
    }
    else {
        $catego = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['cate'][$key]);
        $amo = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['money'][$key]); 
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO cash (category, amount) VALUES ('".$catego."','".$amo."')");
    }
}
```